# Rails and Rake aborted! unknown binary format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when i use any rails or rake commands I get this error:

```
33: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
32: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
31: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
30: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
29: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
28: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
27: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
26: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
25: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
24: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
23: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
22: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
21: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/help/help_command.rb:11:in `help'
20: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:92:in `print_commands'
19: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:102:in `commands'
18: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:102:in `flat_map'
17: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:102:in `each'
16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:12:in `printing_commands'
15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:43:in `formatted_rake_tasks'
14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:34:in `rake_tasks'
13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
 9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
 8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
 6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
 4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:55:in `load_iseq'
 3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:30:in `fetch'
 2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:30:in `fetch'
 1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:19:in `storage_to_output'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:19:in `load_from_binary': unknown binary format (RuntimeError)
```

my environment is ruby 2.6, rails 6, win10, I remember the day before I had the blue screen problem (I think it's related to the hard drive), I was just installing my dependencies with bundle install and then the blue screen problem occurred, shut the pc that day, today this problem happened to me, so maybe the two problems are related? maybe the format in the hard drive that day did change or something.

Comment: Try reinstalling all gems and deleting the tmp directory.

Comment: i did reinstalling all the gems didn't work though, but where do I find the tmp directory?

Answer (score 1):

I run into same problem. I don't think it was HD, I've checked it and it seemed fine, I think it was because I forcefully shut down rails during some rendering operation.

**Solution**

For me I didn't have to re-clone my repo, all I had to do is `rm -rf tmp` (delete tmp folder from project).

Answer (score 0):

the problem was really the hard drive, a section of it was corrupted duo of some hit or shaking (i traveled a lot with my pc at this period), the corrupted files was in the project file not in the ruby gems or in any other projects so, removing the older project and creating a new one solved the problem.